# Using psexec to copy files from local machine to a remote desktop

Tags: psexec

Inorder to copy files from my local system to a remote desktop I use the following command

```
psexec \\192.168.xx.xx -u username -p password  xcopy "C:\Users\User\Desktop\source" "\\192.168.xx.xx\C$\Users\User\Desktop\target"  /S /Y /F /I
```

I am getting a this error

```
0 File(s) copied
`ƒ♦╝# zü┴k
xcopy exited on 192.168.xx.xx with error code 4.
```